# Посчитать процентное соотношение вхождений значения в одном столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня в *csv* файле столбец `native-country` в нём названия стран  мне нужно узнать какова доля отдельно взятой страны относительно других стран в процентах. Причём есть значение со знаком ? (его учитывать не нужно). Не могу понять как это сделать на `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('adult.data.csv')
```

Вывожу сколько всего значений по каждой стране нужного мне столбца:

```
print(df['native-country'].value_counts())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь мне нужно узнать какова доля граждан Германии в процентах по отношению к другим странам. Не могу понять как это дальше сделать на Панде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример исходных данных:

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'country':np.random.choice(['USA','Germany','France'], 1234, 
                                                      p=[.5,.3,.2])})

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
      country
0      France
1         USA
2     Germany
3     Germany
4     Germany
...       ...
1229      USA
1230      USA
1231      USA
1232      USA
1233   France

[1234 rows x 1 columns]

In [10]: df.country.value_counts()
Out[10]:
USA        608
Germany    378
France     248
Name: country, dtype: int64
```

Решение: выберите нужную строку при помощи [df.loc[...]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) и разделите на число строк в исходном DataFrame:

```
In [11]: df['country'].value_counts().loc['Germany'] / len(df)
Out[11]: 0.3063209076175041
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Всё получилось

Comment: @IT-KOT, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;)

Comment: Принял как правильный. Я первый раз здесь)

Comment: @IT-KOT, добро пожаловать на SO! :-)